# Where is the "ancestors" post object attribute?

Tags: posts, debug, oop

I usually work with the `ancestors` attribute of the post object:

```
if ( in_array( $target_id, $post->ancestors ) ) {
  // do whatever
}
```

But while debugging the post object I've seen that there is no trace of it.

Can someone help me understand the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you don't see it if you dump object is because it's not *actual* object property.

`WP_Post` implements magical `__get()` method for `ancestors` and several more keys like that. When you access `$post->ancestors()` what you actually get is not some value from the object, but return of `get_post_ancestors()` function executed on it.

So in a nutshell this is like a virtual API shortcut.